# Make soundclip in a listView selectable as (notification) ringtone?

Tags: java, android, notifications, assign, ringtone

I've got a list of tones which I've made, I've managed to get them into a list but now I'm faced with the challenge of allowing the user to "touch and hold" to assign as a notification tone. Here's the code from MainActivity.java:

```
       import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private ArrayList<Sound> mSounds = null;
private SoundAdapter mAdapter = null;
static MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
this.getListView().setSelector(R.drawable.selector);
//create a simple list
mSounds = new ArrayList<Sound>();
Sound s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Anjels");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.anjels);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Aggro");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.aggro);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Axo");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.axo);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Basix");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.basix);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Bender");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.bender);
mSounds.add(s);
mAdapter = new SoundAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, mSounds);
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){
Sound s = (Sound) mSounds.get(position);
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, s.getSoundResourceId());
mp.start();

}@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
  }
}
```

I also have two other java files, one is a "sound class" and the other a "sound adapter" although I don't think they are relative to my question.

Just so you guys know, it's taken me weeks to get this far as I'm still a freshman in javaland. Any help or examples here would be hot! Hell if you wanna do the work for me then that's even sweeter!

Comment: I don't understand. Why did you take out the `ContextMenu` code?

Comment: Sorry I asked this question before I had figured that part out, have now updated.

Comment: So what is the problem you are having with it now?

Comment: I just want someone to point me in the right direction as to how to go about making it possible to set each sound in the list as a notification tone. I've heard a lot of people talking about URI but I think that is well beyond me. Also it appears as though the ringtones would first have to be copied to SD before they can be used as a ringtone.

Comment: Also I appear to have made a long list array in the main thread which I know is frowned upon, i believe. Starting to wish I'd done it another way :( just wish I had someone to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

> The solution I post is just making it possible for you to detect 
>   the position of the listitem you clicked and set as ringtone (which is not working), inside the `setRingtone` function the magic happens. all code to make the sound as ringtone must be placed in there
>
> Inside the `switch` change the `case id 'main_menu'` to the `item id` from your `menu -> context_menu.xml` like below
>
> > ```
> > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> > <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
> > <item
> >     android:id="@+id/main_menu"
> >     android:title="@string/set_ringtone"
> >     android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
> >     />
> > </menu>
> > ```

Add beneath `onCreateContextMenu` the code below.

```
 @Override
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
     super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
   }
 }

 /*-----------------------------  add code below ------------------------------*/

 @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
        try {
            info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            Log.e("", "bad menuInfo", e);
            return false;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.main_menu:
                setRingtone(item.getItemId(), info.position);
                //Toast.makeText(this, "id = " + item.getItemId() + " pos =     " + info.position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public  void setRingtone(int id, int pos){
        //RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);

        Toast.makeText(this, "id = " + id + " pos = " + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```