# Android context menu not appearing

Tags: java, android, android-contextmenu

My problem is just as it says in the description, the context menu is not appearing on a "touch and hold" from the user. I've got a feeling it could be where I placed `registerForContextMenu`.
Here's my MainActivity:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private ArrayList<Sound> mSounds = null;
private SoundAdapter mAdapter = null;
static MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
this.getListView().setSelector(R.drawable.selector);
//create a simple list
mSounds = new ArrayList<Sound>();
Sound s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Anjels");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.anjels);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Aggro");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.aggro);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Basix");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.basix);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Bender");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.bender);
mSounds.add(s);
mAdapter = new SoundAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, mSounds);
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){
Sound s = (Sound) mSounds.get(position);
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, s.getSoundResourceId());
mp.start();

}
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of Android are you using?

Comment: Target of actual device? Target is api "10" ICS but I'm running an SGS3mini on api "16" Jellybean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching these two lines around

```
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

so it should be

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

Your feeling was correct. Your `ListView` is in your `layout` so you need to inflate it first before registering the `View`

Comment: Can I just ask, so I can learn from this, why does that make a such a difference which line comes first?

Comment: As I said in my last sentence of the answer, your `Views` exist within your `layout` so its like they don't exist until the root `layout` has been inflated. Same reason that if you try to initialize a `View` before calling `setContentView()` it will return `null` and you can't use a method or listener on it

Comment: I hope that makes sense

Comment: Perfect sense yes, I understand now. Thanks. Just wondering, would you be able to have a peek at my other question, its driving me mad. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080679/make-soundclip-in-a-listview-selectable-as-notification-ringtone

Answer (score 0):

I assume that "touch and hold" from the user means "longpress"?

If so, try looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389184/oncreatecontextmenu-and-listview-items) to see if your issues are similar. Perhaps you need to use setOnLongClickListener...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, after a day of head scratching I finally found out what what wrong.